# Ring With Unity As a Direct Sum of Non-Zero Ideals

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with unity. Let $ (a_i),i\in I $ be a family of non-zero ideals of $R$. Suppose that $R$ is a direct sum of the family $ (a_i),i\in I $ (i.e the additive group $R$ is a direct sum of the subgroups  $ a_i,i\in I $). I wish to prove that in this case **$I$ must be a finite set**.

I will explain the argument which I gave until the point of my question:

Take the identity element $ 1\in R $. Since $R$ is the direct sum of the $a_i$, there exists a finite subset $I_0 \subseteq I$ and elements $e_i \in a_i \setminus 0 , i \in I_0$ such that $1 = \sum_{i \in I_0} e_i $. Then, for every $x \in R$ we have $x = x.1 = \sum_{i \in I_0} xe_i \in \sum_{i \in I_0} a_i $ since each $a_i$ is an ideal, and so $R = \sum_{i \in I_0} a_i $.

My idea now is to prove that one must have $I = I_0$, but I have a feeling that I'm missing something trivial. Can anyone help me with this final step if possible? Thank you in advance.

On a final note, I'm assuming that each $a_i$ is an **ideal**, but as far as I was informed, this is also true for **left ideals** (or  **right ideals**).

Comment: Use the independence of summands in direct sum: For every $i \in I \setminus I_0$ it holds that $a_i \cap \sum_{j \in I_0}a_j=0$...

Comment: So, since the $a_i$ are in direct sum, we know that $ a_i \cap \sum_{j \in I\setminus{i}} a_j = 0 $ holds for each $i \in I$. By contradiction, suppose $I \setminus I_0$ is non-empty. Let $i \in I \setminus I_0$. Then $a_i \cap \sum_{j \in I\setminus{i}} a_j = 0$. But $\sum_{j \in I\setminus{i}} a_j = \sum_{j \in I_0} a_j + \sum_{j \in I \setminus (I_0 \cup {i})} a_j = R + \sum_{j \in I \setminus (I_0 \cup {i})} a_j = R $. Then $0 = a_i \cap \sum_{j \in I\setminus{i}} a_j = a_i \cap R = a_i$, a contradiction since every $a_i$ is non-zero by hypothesis. Is this it @PavelC?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notation is a bit awkward. Your given data is a family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of nonzero ideals and you know that, as an abelian group,
$$
R=\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_i
$$
In particular, every element $r\in R$ can be uniquely written as
$$
r=\sum_{i\in I}r_i \qquad(r_i\in A_i)
$$
where all but a finite number of the summands $r_i$ are nonzero.

Let $1=\sum_{i\in I}e_i$ and fix a nonzero element $x_j\in A_j$. Then
$$
x_j=x_j1=x_j\biggl(\sum_{i\in I}e_i\biggr)=\sum_{i\in I}(x_je_i)
$$
By the uniqueness of representation, we must have
$$
x_je_i=\begin{cases}
x_j & \text{if $i=j$}\\
0 & \text{if $i\ne j$}
\end{cases}
$$
because $x_je_i\in A_j$, since $A_j$ is an ideal. In particular, $e_j\ne0$ for all $j\in I$.

Thus $I$ is finite.

Note that only the fact that every $A_i$ is a right ideal has been used. For the case with left ideals, just use $1x_j=x_j$.