# If a sum of ideals is the unit ideal, then 1 can be written as a finite sum of elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

When I read GTM211, I was confused about this question :if a sum of ideals is the unit ideal, then 1 can be written as a finite sum of elements

Comment: Many authors define the sum of a family of ideals to be the set of elements obtainable as finite sums of elements taken from the ideals in the family. With this definition, what you want is immediate, so you probably have a different (though equivalent) definition in mind; you should say what that definition is.

Comment: Second what Andreas said. You aren't talking [about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1093631/29335), are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of a sum of ideals is a (finite) sum of elements, each element from a distinct ideal in the sum.

Thus, if a sum of ideals is $(1)$, then since $1\in (1)$, it follows that $1$ can be so expressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are considering unitary ideals. 
If a unitary ideal is a sum of ideals, then your unitary ideal has the unity (1) and since it is the sum of ideals, every element of it can be expressed as sum of elements of each ideal that is part of the sum, so you can do what you say.