# Semisimple modules

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $M$ be a semisimple $R$-module, where $R$ is a ring. By definition, $M$ is isomorphic to $\oplus_{i=1}^n S_i$, where $S_i$ are simple $R$-modules. Why is the direct sum finite?

Comment: Where did you see this definition? I'm looking at Lang now, and he doesn't have the condition that the direct sum be finite.

Comment: In a lecture. The professor told us that, since R is finitely generated R-module, so is the sum. As a result, we can consider it finite.

Comment: "So is the sum" -- so is which sum?

Comment: Yes, sorry. By definition, M is isomorphic to  a direct sum of simple modules. This sum by definition is not necessarily finite. But it ends up to be finite. This I don't understand

Comment: I think $R$, considered as an $R$-module, has to be a finite direct sum, but a general $R$-module $M$ need not be. I could be wrong.

Comment: You can consider a field k.the infinite dimensional vector space is of course semisimple module.

Answer (score 2):

It frequently isn't finite.

For example $\oplus_{i=1}^\infty F$ is a semisimple module that isn't a finite direct sum.

The case for $R_R$ itself being semisimple is the subject [of this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1093631/29335), which I think you are referring to in the comments.  Certainly the same cannot be said for arbitrary modules.